# p:command to submit a form in overlaypanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I am trying to put a p:commandButton inside a overlayPanel, to submit the information of a h:form and redirect to another view. So, I use the property action of the button to perform this operation. I have a managed bean associated with this view but the function used for this purpose is never reached. Can u help me?

Here is the code:

advancedSearch-form.xhtml

```
      <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid width="100%">
            <h:column>
             ....

            </h:column>

             ....

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{searchForm.save}">

            </p:commandButton>

        </h:panelGrid>
```

In another xhtml:

```
        <h:form>
            <div>
                ...
                <div class="menu-search">
                     <p:commandButton id="advancedSearch" icon="ui-icon-carat-1-s" styleClass="ui-search-button" type="button"/>
                        <p:overlayPanel id="advancedSearchPanel" styleClass="ui-advanced-search-overlay" for="advancedSearch" hideEffect="fade" my="right top" dynamic="true" dismissable="false">
                          <ui:include src="/search/advancedSearch-form.xhtml"/>                        
                        </p:overlayPanel>
                </div>
                ...
           </div>
```

Comment: Plese add the code, it will help to answer quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking over the properties of overlay, I solved this question by removing the dynamic property of overlaypanel.